# How can I make postman respect the security override of an operation in Open API Spec

Tags: postman, openapi

I have an Open API Spec that defined a security scheme for the API and then an operation that needs to opt out of that security scheme. When I render the spec in VSCode with the OpenAPI extension, I can clearly see by the lack of a lock icon, there is no auth required for that operation. When I import the spec into Postman as an API, the endpoint is grouped with other endpoints based on path affinity and the no-auth operation is set to inherit the scheme from the API.

#### Is this just a missing feature of Postman or am I doing something wrong?

rendered spec:
[image]

imported spec:
[image]

Comment: This looks like a bug/limitation of Postman's OpenAPI importer. Open an issue with Postman.